# Parse through hierarchical, mixed data text file to create a table in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parsing

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I am trying to parse through a very large text file. I can’t change the format of the file directly, only through code. I have seen somewhat similar questions but not as specific and the solutions do not work for it.

The file is formatted like so:

```
Title
{
  “10”: { # part of group 10
    “1”: { # part of section 1
      “Number”: [
        3.0,
        4.0,
        5.0
      ],
      “Date”: [
        “2023-4”,
        “2023-5”,
        “2023-6”
      ],
      “Time”: [
        “08:03:49”,
        “09:45:21”,
        “06:34:01”
      ]
    },
    “2”:
      “Number”: [
#not writing similar values out for simplicity but the values would look similar to the group 10 section 1.
  }, #end of group 10
  “11”: {
    “1”: 
      “Number”: [
# you get the point I hope
```

The first line is not indented, the line for group is indented 2 spaces, section is indented 4 spaces, the data labels are indented 6 spaces, and the actual values for the data is indented 8 spaces.

So, I need this to be parsed into a table in python with the table column names being: Group, Section, Number, Date, and Time.

Since there will be multiple section for each group, the group number needs to be filled in with for the section. This is the same for number, date, and time slots.
An example would be something like this:

```
Group  Section  Number   Date    Time   
10     1        3.0      2023-4  08:03:49   
10     1        4.0      2023-5  09:45:21   
…   
10     2        4.0      2023-2  07:43:33   
…
11     1        3.0      2023-4  08:03:49   
11     1        4.0      2023-5  09:45:21
11     2        3.0      2023-4  08:03:49   
11     3        4.0      2023-5  09:45:21


# I reused some numbers to make it easier since this is fake data
```

I think I’m struggling with the hierarchical form, and filling in the group in section when they each have multiple pieces of data that are a part of them. Also, just the fact that there isn’t one single delimiter and I can’t directly change the original text file.

Any help would be very greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Double quotes are really [`“`](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+201C) or [`"`](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0022)?

Comment: The second one. Apologies for that, I did not realize there was a difference.

Comment: So do you know what is the actually double quote characters? It's important for me :-)

Comment: I think you mean that there is a difference in unicode characters. Which I learned from your links, that was very helpful by the way. " - like this instead. I can update it in my question. Please correct me if I’ve misinterpreted your inquiry.

Comment: Yes. Your file is near from a Python dict syntax (except the first line and missing comma in list). Does your file contain comments #?

Comment: It does not contain comments.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to convert your file into a Python dictionary by

- fixing unicode double quotes
- append a comma to each element of the lists

Then I use `eval` to convert as a dict and finally convert it to a DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

in_list = False
with open('data.txt') as fp:
    fp.readline() # skip firstline
    lines = []
    for line in fp:
        line = line.replace('“', '"').replace('”', '"').rstrip()
        if line.endswith('['):
            in_list = True
        elif line.endswith(']') or line.endswith('],'):
            in_list = False
        elif in_list:
            line += ','
        lines.append(line)
    data = eval('\n'.join(lines))

df = (pd.DataFrame.from_dict({(g, s): data[g][s] for g in data for s in data[g]}, orient='index')
        .rename_axis(['Group', 'Section'])
        .explode(['Number', 'Date', 'Time']).reset_index())
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   Group Section Number    Date      Time
0     10       1    3.0  2023-4  08:03:49
1     10       1    4.0  2023-5  09:45:21
2     10       1    5.0  2023-6  06:34:01
3     10       2    3.0  2023-4  08:03:49
4     10       2    4.0  2023-5  09:45:21
5     10       2    5.0  2023-6  06:34:01
6     11       1    3.0  2023-4  08:03:49
7     11       1    4.0  2023-5  09:45:21
8     11       1    5.0  2023-6  06:34:01
9     11       2    3.0  2023-4  08:03:49
10    11       2    4.0  2023-5  09:45:21
11    11       2    5.0  2023-6  06:34:01
```

Comment: Hi sorry for the late response. I unexpected had to shift gears and switch projects. Thank you for responding, I am currently tweaking this as I doesn’t seem to account for colons after Number, Date, and Time to throw them into their own column of data. Thanks again for taking the time to work out a solution.

Comment: I am also getting ValueError from the explode function that “column must be a scalar”